# viewport doesn't work in android Chrome

Tags: css, responsive-design, viewport

I want my page to look the same in both android and desktop under the same resolution e.g `1280*720` so I added:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, target-densitydpi=device-dpi, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />
```

But while the page looks perfect with desktop Google chrome, it is displayed only partially in mobile android browser. `$(window).width` returns `1280` for desktop chrome but it returned only `360` in android chrome (The resolution for the desktop and android phone is the same `1280*720`).

Comment: You got any code? Or links to the page in question?

Comment: If it's retina display than the pixel ration is 2: 360x2 = 720. Try it without `width=device-width`.

Comment: ...and don't use these...`user-scalable=no`, `maximum-scale=1`. Its not recommended and offers a very poor user experience.